# What is Logging, and how is Apache Commons logging used?

Tags: java, logging, interface, apache-commons, apache-commons-logging

What information would a web application server wish to log, and why?

From what I understand

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log
```

is an interface that abstracts the functionality provided by other Logging classes, and the same applies to the interface LogFactory.

Code I am trying to understand has -

```
Log auditLogger = LogFactory.getLog(someString);
```

How is the String someString used to identify what LogFactory to generate? How can I see the implementation of the Log and LogFactory classes being used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string is an arbitrary `identifier` which we can use to **redirect** or **filter** the logging output. One common approach is to use the className, e.g.,

```
Log auditLogger = LogFactory.getLog(MyCurrentClass.class);
```

As you said, `commons-logging` is a facade which defaults to `java.util.logging` if no other logging library is supplied. 
I would recommend to put a logging implementation such as [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/), [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/), or [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) in the *classpath*.

Assuming you put e.g., `log4j` there you can control the logging output using a configuration file `log4j.xml`, such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log4j:configuration>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        ..... 
    </appender>


    <!-- Send debug information from "com.company.MyCurrentClass" to CONSOLE -->
    <logger name="com.company.MyCurrentClass">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

`someString` is just logger name (or alias if you want, usually class name).
You not need to know implementation of `Log` and `LogFactory` just configure and use it.

Information that web application should to log is what developer of this application want to know (e.g. handling of exceptions, some state flow, other useful information)

Answer (score 1):

We're using code similar to `Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MyCurrentClass.class);` in our web layer (Struts2 Actions or JSF Backing Beans) as well as our EJB 3 Session Beans.

We then primarily log errors and warnings but usefull information, too (like the start and end of a scheduled job, user login, certain user actions to see what they were doing just before an error occured etc.).

You also might want to use `logger.debug("Debug message")` to log more information when the logging framework is enabled to accept those (in Log4J you would set the threshold to DEBUG or lower, which can be done at runtime). If the debug message first needs to be extracted/assembled etc. which might be too expensive for the common case where you don't need it, you could first check `logger.isDebugEnabled()`.

Generally, each logger gets a name which you provide to the LogFactory.getLog() method, either as a string or class. This enables you to set different settings per logger or group.

For example, if you have a logger for `my.package.MyClass` and use a library with package `org.library.*` you could configure the logging framework to enable debug messages for `my.package.*` but not for `org.library.*`. This way you can filter messages in order to get a smaller/better readable log.